# IIS 8.5 Max File Upload Size

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I already have my max file size maxed out in IIS 8.5, but is there a solution that would let me upload even larger files??

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to upload the very large file to the server, I suggest you could firstly divided the large file to chunks and then generate multiple request to upload the chunks to the server.

If all the chunks are uploaded completely, then you could combine the chunks to the final file.

For exmaple, you could use [jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), it support upload file with chunks.

Details, you could refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33243837/7609093